# PyQt: Call a TrayMinimized application

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have an application wich is minimized to the tray (showing an icon) when the user close it. What I need to know is how can I call it back with a combination of keys, like Ctrl+Alt+Something. Actually I call it back when I double-click it, but it will be nice to do the same on a keystroke. Here is a portion of the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""The user interface for our app"""

import os,sys
import ConfigParser

# Import Qt modules
from PyQt4 import QtCore,QtGui

# Import the compiled UI module
from octo import Ui_Form
CFG_PATH = "etc/config.list"   #Config File Path
#config.list vars DEFAULT Values
ClipCount = 8
Static = ""
window = None


# Create a class for our main window
class Main(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)        
        # This is always the same
        self.ui=Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        # Window Icon
        icon = QtGui.QIcon("SSaver.ico")    
        self.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.setWindowTitle("Octopy")     
        # Set the timer =)      
        self.timer = self.startTimer(1000) #self.killTimer(self.timer)
        # Clipboard Counter
        self.counter = 0
        #Last trapped clipboard
        self.LastClip = ""           
        self.tentacles = [""] * 8  

        self.cmd = []
        self.cmd.append(self.ui.cmd_1)
        self.cmd.append(self.ui.cmd_2)
        self.cmd.append(self.ui.cmd_3)
        self.cmd.append(self.ui.cmd_4)
        self.cmd.append(self.ui.cmd_5)
        self.cmd.append(self.ui.cmd_6)                                        
        self.cmd.append(self.ui.cmd_7)
        self.cmd.append(self.ui.cmd_8)                

## Events ##          
    def on_cmd_8_pressed(self): #Clear
        for i in range(0,7):
            self.tentacles[i] = ""            
            self.cmd[i].setText(self.tentacles[i])  


    def on_cmd_1_pressed(self):
        t = self.ui.cmd_1.text()
        self.setClp(t)

    def on_cmd_2_pressed(self):
        t = self.ui.cmd_2.text()
        self.setClp(t)

    def on_cmd_3_pressed(self):
        t = self.ui.cmd_3.text()
        self.setClp(t)

    def on_cmd_4_pressed(self):
        t = self.ui.cmd_4.text()
        self.setClp(t)

    def on_cmd_5_pressed(self):
        t = self.ui.cmd_5.text()
        self.setClp(t)

    def on_cmd_6_pressed(self):
        t = self.ui.cmd_6.text()
        self.setClp(t)

    def on_cmd_7_pressed(self):                        
        t = self.ui.cmd_7.text()
        self.setClp(t)

    def hideEvent(self,event): # Capture close and minimize events
        pass

    def keyPressEvent(self,ev):
        if ev.key() == 16777216:
            self.hide()

    def showEvent(self,ev):
        self.fillClp()       

    def timerEvent(self,ev):
        c = self.getClp()           
        if c:                        
            #print c, self.counter 
            self.tentacles[self.counter] = c
            if self.counter < 7:
                self.counter += 1
            else:
                self.counter = 0

            self.fillClp()

## Functions ##
    def fillClp(self):
        for i in range(0,7):
            self.cmd[i].setText(self.tentacles[i])   

    def getClp(self):
        clp = QtGui.QApplication.clipboard() 
        c = clp.text()                        
        if self.LastClip != c:
            self.LastClip = c
            return c
        else:
            return None

    def setClp(self, t):               
        clp = QtGui.QApplication.clipboard() 
        clp.setText(t)        


class SystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon):
    def __init__(self, icon, parent=None):
        QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.__init__(self, icon, parent)
        menu = QtGui.QMenu(parent)                
        # Actions
        self.action_quit = QtGui.QAction("Quit", self)
        self.action_about = QtGui.QAction("About Octopy", self)
        # Add actions to menu
        menu.addAction(self.action_about)
        menu.addSeparator()
        menu.addAction(self.action_quit)
        # Connect menu with signals
        self.connect(self.action_about, QtCore.SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.about)       
        self.connect(self.action_quit, QtCore.SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.quit) 
        # Other signals
        traySignal = "activated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)"
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL(traySignal), self.icon_activated)
        # Create Menu               
        self.setContextMenu(menu)

    def quit(self):
        w = QtGui.QWidget()
        reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(w, 'Confirm Action',"Are you sure to quit?", QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes, QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:           
            QtGui.QApplication.quit()

    def about(self):            
        w = QtGui.QWidget()
        QtGui.QMessageBox.information(w, 'About', "Octopy Multi-Clipboard Manager\n Developed by mRt.")

    def icon_activated(self, reason):
        if reason == QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.DoubleClick:
            window.show()
        else:
            print "otro"     


def main():
    # Again, this is boilerplate, it's going to be the same on 
    # almost every app you write
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)        
    # TrayIcon
    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    icon = QtGui.QIcon("SSaver.ico")          
    trayIcon = SystemTrayIcon(icon, w)
    trayIcon.show()    
    trayIcon.setToolTip("Octopy Multi-Clipboard Manager")    
    # Main Window
    global window    
    window=Main()
    window.show()    
    window.setWindowTitle("Octopy")
    app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(0)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())    


def readIni():
    cfg = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    cfg.read(CFG_PATH)
    ClipCount = int(cfg.get("Other","ClipCount"))
    Static = cfg.get("Other","Static")
    clip = [""] * int(ClipCount+1)    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    readIni()
    main()
```

The complete program is hosted on google: http://code.google.com/p/octopys/downloads/list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a keystroke to be handled by your application when it does not have keyboard focus, you need to install a global shortcut. Qt doesn't support this, but Qxt, a Qt extension library, does. See 
http://doc.libqxt.org/0.5.0/classQxtGlobalShortcut.html. I don't know if PyQt bindings exist for Qxt.